# Babel.js require hook with plugin

Tags: babeljs

I didn't find it in babel docs so asking here.

I want to use babel-rewire-plugin in my nodejs project.
I'm using babel by require hook:

```
require('babel/register')
```

and i'm wonder how to add babel-rewire-plugin to be used with this hook.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `require` hook can take options. Or you can make a `.babelrc` file.

```
require('babel/register')({
    plugins: ['babel-require-plugin']
});
```